# How to find last element of a javascript object without loop?

Tags: object

**My object is**:

```
{
  "CountryName": { "IsAll": "1", "Dependency": "" },
  "DivisionName": { "IsAll": "0", "Dependency": "RegionName" },
  "DistrictName": { "IsAll": "0", "Dependency": "" },
  "ThanaName": { "IsAll": "1", "Dependency": "" }
}
```

**I want to find** `"ThanaName": { "IsAll": "1", "Dependency": "" }`

Comment: Javascript objects are unordered, so there's no such thing as a "last" element

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var obj = {
  "CountryName": { "IsAll": "1", "Dependency": "" },
  "DivisionName": { "IsAll": "0", "Dependency": "RegionName" },
  "DistrictName": { "IsAll": "0", "Dependency": "" },
  "ThanaName": { "IsAll": "1", "Dependency": "" } 
}  
var totalKeys = Object.keys(obj).length;
var key = Object.keys(obj)[totalKeys-1];
console.log(key,obj[key])
```

But this may not work in all cases, [see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525795/does-javascript-guarantee-object-property-order)